# Laravel Eloquent setting up a subquery in the select part of the SQL

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

```
SELECT *, (
    SELECT count(id) FROM order_history oh 
    WHERE oh.refund_of = oh1.id
) "refunds"
FROM order_history oh1 
WHERE `object_name` 
NOT LIKE '%refund%'
```

I need to translate this into eloquent hopefully without using Db::raw

Comment: Add your database structure

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add a sub select query with the method `select()` or `addSelect()` as shown [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#selects).

Example:

```
select(DB::raw(count(id) FROM order_history oh WHERE oh.refund_of = oh1.id))
```

> Note: "These expressions will be injected into the query as strings, so be careful not to create any SQL injection points!"